# PL\SQL use ORDER BY in UNION query

Tags: plsql

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT
    USERS.*,
    ROWNUM AS RANK ,
    4101   AS TOTAL
FROM
   ( (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            USER_LIST
        WHERE
            USER_LIST.USR_ID = 1)
        UNION(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            USER_LIST)
    ) USERS
```

Which works completely fine, I would like to sort the results via 'ORDER BY'.
I've tried placing the 'ORDER BY' before the last parenthesis (before the USERS) but I get an error, please advise how can I use 'ORDER BY' in this query.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `) USERS Order by ...`

Comment: Just a slightly non-related thing came to my mind after having seen your code. I believe, it would be way more efficient if you used `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` and simply exclude the desired `USR_ID` from the second subquery (e.g. `WHERE USER_LIST.USR_ID != 1`). This would use the index plus get rid of the comparing result sets of those two subqueries. `UNION` greatly extends the time of query execution when it compares any larger result sets (sometimes even when one's fetching less than a hundred of records).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need define `order by` after **alias**.

```
SELECT USERS.*,
         ROWNUM  AS RANK,
         4101    AS TOTAL
FROM ((SELECT * FROM USER_LIST WHERE USER_LIST.USR_ID = 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM USER_LIST)) USERS ORDER BY ...
```